# How to extract unique frames from a credit roll

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video-processing

From a credits roll video file like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM0SG.gif

How can I extract unique frames with ffmpeg? With unique frames I mean next image should start where exactly previous one ended.

Main goal is to then combine them together into one image file which I already know how to do with vstack filter. But extracting the required images is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: No automated way to do this with ffmpeg as far as I know. If you know the distance of movement per frame or second you could possibly make a rough estimate of which frames to extract. But you'll probably just have to extract all frames and then manually match them.

Comment: @llogan yeah looks like it. I thought maybe something can be done with ffmpeg's scene change detection filters etc.. don't know. It would be nice to automate it since I had intention to do it on lots of files. Thanks for your comment.